# Changing permissions in a Unix directory

Tags: linux, permissions, python

I am not able to change permission on a directory I created on the Unix server.

This is how the structure looks

```
$ ls
engany  N832342  N854431  zabbix
$
```

Now I want to change the permission in N854431 folder so that I can read, write and execute files there.

Reason being currently when I am trying to scp some file from my local to that folder it gives an error "Permission Denied"

When I do this:

```
$ ls -l 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 engany  engany  4096 Jan 16 08:46 engany
drwxr-xr-x  3 N832342 N832342 4096 Jan 15 05:30 N832342
drwxr-xr-x  5 N854431 N854431 4096 Jan 16 09:25 N854431
drwxr-xr-x 16 zabbix  zabbix  4096 Jan 10 22:51 zabbix
$
```

I want rwx permission for any directory under N854431.

So I did this:

$ chmod -R ugo+rwx /home/N854431 
And now I see rwx permission in N854431

```
$ ls -l
total 44
-rwxrwxrwx 1 N854431 N854431  8980 Apr 20  2016 examples.desktop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 N854431 N854431 24971 Jan 16 10:14 file.py
drwxrwxrwx 4 N854431 N854431  4096 Jan 16 10:08 web_path
$
```

However now when I try to send a file from my local to a directory under N854431

```
$ scp file.py N854431@10.6.121.124:/web_path
```

gives "Permission Denied" error.

When I do just the directory

```
$ scp file.py N854431@10.6.121.124:
```

It is able to send file.py under N854431. But it is not sending it to any other directory under N854431.

What is going wrong

Comment: You probably want `~/web_path`, not `/web_path`

Comment: when i do this: 

ssh N854431@10.6.121.124 it logs me to 

/home/N854431/. Thats why it also sends the file.py to this folder as mentioned last

Comment: When you start a path with `/`, that makes it absolute, not relative to your starting location.

Comment: Isn't N854431@10.6.121.124: before takes u to /home/10.6.121.124?

Comment: Do u also know how can I remove write permission for Others now? I added ugo. I want rwx permission in all directories under N854431

Comment: Got the removal part.

Comment: Might there be an existing /web_path/file.py ?